# I need to count the filtered words but I won't get any output

Tags: javascript

I need to make a sentence reverser with Javascript. The reversing part and displaying that works. The wordcount with my filter does not work. I want to count the words that contain my filter string.

Example:

> filter: "e"
> sentence: "Yes I don't know"
>
> output: "1 word(s) have been filtered."

```js
let knop = document.getElementById("button");

function reverser() {
  let output = document.getElementById("outputWoorden");

  let filterField = document.getElementById("filterInput");
  let filterValue = filterField.value;
  let input = document.getElementById("tekstInput");
  let text = input.value;
  let filterAmount = document.getElementById("filterAantal");
  let filterNumber = filterAmount.value;
  let array = [];
  let count = 0;

  array += text.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
  for (let i = 0; array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].filter(filterValue)) { //this part is wrong
      array.reduce(array[i]);
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  filterNumber.value = count + "word(s) filtered.";
  output.value = array;
}

knop.addEventListener("click", reverser);
```

```html
Input: <input id="tekstInput"><br>
Filter: <input id="filterInput"><br>
Amount: <input id="filterAantal"><br>
Output: <input id="outputWoorden">
<button id="button">Filter</button>
```

The output should be the correct amount of filtered words.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `array +=`? You can't add arrays.

Comment: `array` is a string, not an array. So `array[i]` is a single character. But `filter()` is an array method. Your code makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I am sorry, I just started learning JavaScript a couple of weeks ago. My teacher is not the most usefull..

Comment: `split` turns a string into an array of words. `reverse` reverses the array. Then `join` turns it back into a string, so it's no longer an array. You should leave out the `join` when you're assigning to the array variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the array, don't use `join` to turn it back into a string first.

You shouldn't loop over the array and also call `filter`. Filter is called directly on the array. Its argument is a function that tests whether the element matches your criteria. The method that tests whether a string contains another string is `includes()`.

The `filter()` method returns an array of all the elements that match the criteria. So if you want to remove the matching words, you have to invert the  test using the logical *not* operator `!`.

You can get the count of removed words by subtracting the length of the original array from the length of the filtered array.

```js
let knop = document.getElementById("button");

function reverser() {
  let output = document.getElementById("outputWoorden");

  let filterField = document.getElementById("filterInput");
  let filterValue = filterField.value;
  let input = document.getElementById("tekstInput");
  let text = input.value;
  let filterAmount = document.getElementById("filterAantal");
  let array = text.split(" ");
  let filtered = array.filter(word => !word.includes(filterValue));
  let reversed = filtered.reverse().join(" ");
  let count = array.length - filtered.length;
  filterAmount.value = count + " word(s) filtered.";
  output.value = reversed;
}

knop.addEventListener("click", reverser);
```

```html
Input: <input id="tekstInput"><br>
Filter: <input id="filterInput"><br>
Amount: <input id="filterAantal"><br>
Output: <input id="outputWoorden">
<button id="button">Filter</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou for correcting me on the '.join' and making it more clear. This looks a lot easier than my mess but the filter does not work. I made the changes to the code.

Comment: The filter code works for me. I tried your example and it said 1 word contains the string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use StackOverflow that much, I just started using it actually. Maybe I was not clear enough, I also need to filter out the words that contain the filtered string. The counter should increase and the amount of words that contain the string should be removed from the string.

Comment: The question just says you want to count the words that match the filter, it doesn't say anything about removing them.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please clarify the question.

Comment: The input field (the one I use to show the reversed and filtered words) does show me the words that should be filtered out. The output phrase does not show the amount of words that are filtered. ("0 word(s) are filtered."). How can I update that phrase? I got a 'hard coded' (If you can call it like that) sentence to start with. "0 word(s) have been filtered". After the button "click" event I would like to update that sentence to the correct amount of words that have been filtered. I hope this is clear enough. Like you already said, I've been very unclear with my questions :(

Comment: It works for me, I don't know what you're doing differently. When I try your example it says 1 word filtered.

Comment: And if I filter `o` it says 2 words filtered.

Comment: I've had a lot of strange experiences with Javascript. I copied the code and it does not work. I am using WebStorm to write the code. Could that be a problem perhaps (would be very weird)?

Comment: The code runs in the browser, it shouldn't matter how you wrote it.